# Is it possible to remove SAN from a certificate?

Tags: ssl, certificate, openssl, ssl-certificate

I've bought a certificate from an online provider.

The CSR only contains a single SN (`mysubdomain.example.com`).

The certificate issued, contains the SN i provided in my CSR, but for some reason the certificate  is provided with a SAN that I didn't request (`mysubdomain.example.com` and `www.mysubdomain.example.com`)

I verified this by issuing the following command on the PEM file:

```bsh
$ openssl x509 -text -noout -in certificate.pem | grep DNS
DNS:mysubdomain.example.com, DNS:www.mysubdomain.example.com
```

Is it possible to modify the certificate to only have the original SN as stated in my CSR?

The provider of the certificate is not willing to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to modify the certificate ...

It is not possible to modify the certificate, no matter what changes you want to do. Any modifications would invalidate the signature of the issuer CA on the certificate. But an invalid signature would make the whole certificate invalid.